# GLUU client does not have permission for SCIM requests

Tags: scim, gluu

I have a client that is making a [getUser](https://www.gluu.org/docs/api/scim-1.1/) SCIM request. It successfully can get an access token and RPT, however when it actually comes to the getUser request, I get a response with the status '403 Forbidden' with a ticket as the body of the response. According to this [UMA document](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/draft-uma-core.html#ticket-management) a permission ticket indicates the request was valid, but the client does not have permission. I have tried everything I can think of to give this client permissions, but havent managed to get it working.

Does anyone know how to give a client permissions to do SCIM requests?

My current method of attempting a request is:

1. Get access token using client credentials
2. Get RPT using access token acquired in step 1 as authorization
3. make domain.com/identity/seam/resource/restv1/scim/v1/Users request using RPT as authorization
4. Follow the [seek authorization steps](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/rec-uma-core.html#seek-authorization) of sending request to RPT endpoint with ticket and old RPT. This replies with a new RPT.
5. Attempt step 3 again using the RPT from step 4 as authorization

Any advice would be appreciated.